# Illegal assignment expression in continuous assignment. Verilog Octal 2 to 1 Mux

Tags: verilog, modelsim, multiplexing

I'm trying to code an Octal (8-bit inputs) 2-to-1 Multiplexer.  Here is my code:

```
module octal2to1mux(input [7:0] a, input [7:0] b, input s, output w);

assign w= (s=1'b0) ? a:
          (s=1'b1) ? b: 1'bx;
endmodule
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
octal2to1mux.sv(3): Illegal assignment expression in continuous assignment.
```

I just want to get w=a if s=0 and w=b if s=1. a and b are both 8-bit inputs. I use this module twice in the testbench.

Comment: I think that you wanted `(s == 1'b0 )` instead of just `=`.

Comment: @Serge that was it. Its just that the single = code is what the prof gave us so I am a little confused. I was hesitant to change it.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to code a synthesizable mux is:

```
module octal2to1mux (input [7:0] a, input [7:0] b, input s, output [7:0] w);
    assign w = (s) ? a : b;
endmodule
```

It is simpler, easier to understand and fixes your syntax error.  Also, if `s` is `X` or `Z`, then `w` will be `X`; there is no need to explicitly set it to `X`.

Note that `w` must be the same bit width as the `a` and `b` inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The output `w` shall have a width of 8.
And as @Serge commented, when comparing, `==` or `===` (not synthesizable) should be used.